# a few questions about thread synchronization

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

```
class Q {
int n;
boolean sse = false;
synchronized int get(){
    while (!sse)
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Interrupted Exception Caught");
        }
    System.out.println("Got :" + n);
    sse = false;
    notify();
    return n;
        }
synchronized void put(int n){
    while(sse)
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
         System.out.println("Caught");
        }
    this.n = n;
    sse = true;
    System.out.println("Put :" + n);
    notify();
}

}
class Producer implements Runnable{
    Q q;
    Producer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Prodcuer").start();
    }
    public void run(){
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
        q.put(i++);
        }
    }
}
class Consumer implements Runnable{
    Q q;
    Consumer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
    }
    public void run(){

        while(true) {
        q.get();
        }
    }
}
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
  Q q = new Q();
  new Producer(q);
  new Consumer(q);
  System.out.println("Press Control C to stop");
    }

}
```

I have 2 questions.

Q1. now the definition of wait() function is like this : tells the calling thread to give up monitor and go to sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls notify().
Now in this program two threads(One related to consumer and one to producer) use the same object q in get and put respectively. So is there only one monitor existing for the object q, which is entered when any thread uses a function involving q?

Q2 Here the Consumer waits until Producer notifies it, but the Producer also waits until the consumer notifies it? Who starts first?
In the output, Producer comes first but how?

Comment: I think you need to read up on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) before you start using such mechanisms.

Comment: in other multithreaded programs, that comes first which is called first from main( due to i think a little overhead) but here the queue is empty initially and even if producer comes first, it is blocked.

Comment: all that stuff i have already read. whatever you think is relevant maybe you can concisely tell me?

Comment: @Abhay Saini, I'm sorry, but I'm really struggling to understand your questions. what are you looking for?

Comment: maybe some default mechanism allows Producer to bypass first wait() function? Am i right?

Comment: @Abhay Saini, you "bypass" the first `wait()` because `sse` is initialized to `false`, and therefore you don't enter the `while` loop in `put(int n)`

Comment: Q1         Does every object (like q in this case) posses their own monitor, WHICH is entered when a thread uses that object.? Is this statement true or false?                      Q2           How is Product thread bypassing the wait() function when the consumer hasn't consumed anything?

Comment: @mre, yes i got the 2nd question(really stupid to overlook that) but what about the 1st?

Comment: @Abhay Saini, According to the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29), the current thread must own this object's monitor. Therefore, I believe `main` owns Q's monitor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Q has just one monitor
2. Producer starts first because you called its constructor first in your Main.

Comment: What is the mechanism of the program? I mean, if we go step by step something like a deadlock is formed?

Comment: And q or Q? I thought objects had their own monitors?

Comment: There is no guarantee whose thread's run method will be called first. It is probable that the thread whose `start` method is called first will be first start to run, but it could be the other way around, or both at the same time.

Comment: @Abhay: Each Q object will have its own monitor. In your program you have only one Q object (the one which is in the various `q` variables), thus there will be only one (used) monitor at all.

Answer (score 0):

About the second question: When your program starts, the Q object "is empty", which means there is no object that the consumer could get. Thus the consumer has to wait until the producer puts something in. This means the producer will first print its "Put", then the consumer can retrieve it and print its "Get".

On the other hand, if the producer tries to put something again before the consumer had taken the previous element out of the queue, the producer has to wait until it is taken.

This means you will get alternating "Put" and "Get" output (assuming the output stream does not do some reordering).

This differs a bit from `SynchronousQueue` in that here the producer can proceed if the queue was empty before (and the consumer can proceed if it was full before), while for SynchronousQueue it would wait until the consumer is ready to take it (which means `put` and `get` are **always** overlapping in time, and can't be called on the same thread).

Your queue is more similar to an ArrayBlockingQueue with capacity 1.

Comment: There is no alternate Put and Get, they come in one order. Put 1 Get 1 Put 2 Get 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

1. Each object (instance) in jvm has exactly one monitor. This is crucial for achieving the intended behavior (i.e. ensuring that only one thread from a bunch of threads goes ahead while others wait).

   You can visualize the lock as a kind of token/pass that is needed for entering a room. Many hospitals employ such a scheme to ensure that only a single attendant can be with a particular patient. If you want to take place of current attendant, you should `wait()` for the current attendant to come out and hand over the pass to you. Only then you can go pass the security to enter the restricted area. Off course this scheme only works if there is only one token/pass per patient. Otherwise it will be impossible for the security personnel to know which patient already have an attendant.
2. With your code, the producer thread will start first because you are creating the producer before the consumer. But if you want to know which one of the `get()` or `put()` be called first then there is no guarantee of the order. In practice you will usually see the `put()` being called first because the producer thread was started first. But theoretically there remains possibility of seeing the `get()` called first. This is possible because thread scheduler might switch out the producer thread before it reaches the put() call.